# Когда стоит отключать ObjectTrackingEnabled?

Tags: c#, linq, linq2sql

Для увелечения проиводительности DataContext рекомендуется отключать `ObjectTracking`([источник](http://www.sidarok.com/web/blog/content/2008/05/02/10-tips-to-improve-your-linq-to-sql-application-performance.html)) если, цитирую:

> If you are trying only to retrieve data as read only, and not modifying anything, you don’t need object tracking

```
using (NorthwindDataContext context = new NorthwindDataContext())
{
    context.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
}
```

Когда стоит это делать? Когда я просто вывожу данные из БД, например?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, `ObjectTrackingEnabled` имеет смысл только при длительных использованиях соответствующих контекстов, так как в случае, если контекст используется как короткий `unit of work` для некоторого получения данных, то смысла в `ObjectTrackingEnabled` немного.

Во-вторых *(что достаточно важно)*, установка `ObjectTrackingEnabled` хороша тем, что **автоматически запрещаются любые изменения данных** в области текущего `unit of work`, что вполне может позволить избежать нежелательных результатов.

---

Как вариант для удобного использования могу предложить короткий `fluent extension` метод:

```
public static class DataContextExtensions
{
    public static T TrackingDisabled<T>(this T dataContext) where T : DataContext
    {
        dataContext.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
        return dataContext;
    }   
}
```

Таким образом, ваш код в соответствующем `read-only` случае может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
using (var dataContext = new CustomDataContext(...).TrackingDisabled())
```

Answer (score 2):

Через `DataContext` можно не только делать запросы к БД, но и обновлять данные в БД. Для этого предназначены методы `DataContext.SubmitChanges`, `Table.DeleteOnSubmit`, `Table.InsertOnSubmit` и пр. Если не требуется обновлять данные через `DataContext`, то отслеживание состояния объектов можно отключить.

Comment: допустим у меня есть ``CompiledQuery``:

    _getMessages = CompiledQuery.Compile<ForumDataContext, Func<Messages, bool>, IEnumerable<Messages>>((dataContext, predicate) => dataContext.Messages.Where(predicate)));

я его использую следующим образом:

    public static IEnumerable<Messages> GetMessages(Func<Messages,bool> predicate)
        {
            using (var fdc = new ForumDataContext())
            {
                return _getMessages.Value(fdc, predicate);
            }
        }

Comment: Можете. Только использование предиката в виде Func<Messages,bool> убьёт не только прирост производительности, даваемый классом `CompiledQuery`, но и производительность интерпретируемых запросов. Такой запрос будет выполняться так: у Вас выкачивается вся таблица Messages, конвертируется в объекты, а уже потом фильтруется по переданному предикату. Рекомендую разобраться, как выполняются интерпретируемые запросы и что делает класс CompliedQuery, чтобы не делать таких ошибок.

Comment: и правда, спасибо, приму к сведению!

Comment: а где лучше отключать? на уровне ``CompiledQuery`` или на уровне метода ``GetMessages``

Comment: Если не вдаваться в подробности, то Вам, прежде всего, необходимо сделать так, чтобы в `CompiledQuery` в качестве второго параметра передавались только данные, но не делегаты. А насчёт того, где отключать - посмотрите ответ участника Котик хочет кушать. Нормальное, элегантное решение.

Comment: да, ``CompiledQuery`` я исправил, ещё раз спасибо.